# check box to accepet terms and conditions when submitting a form - Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, database, forms, laravel-8

i made a form that will submit the data to database

but i want the user to accept the terms and conditions before submitting the form

example:

[image]

how is it possible to make it in Laravel 8?

Comment: Add required attribute to <input type='checkbox' required>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
<input type="checkbox"
    class="form-check-input @error('terms') is-invalid @enderror"
    value="true"
    name="terms"
    id="keep-signed"
    {{ !old('terms') ?: 'checked' }}
>
<label class="form-check-label fs-sm">
    {{ __('I agree to') }}
    <a class="nav-link-style fs-ms text-black-50 text-primary text-decoration-none" href="#">
        {{ __('Terms & Conditions') }}
    </a>
</label>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).